# Function fires multiple times because 1st function is slow

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I'm trying to implement the jQuery autocomplete.

The autocomplete call takes 500ms to load the list. During those 500ms, if user types more characters, the autocomplete fires again, resulting in duplicate listings.

How can I limit the call to only happen once?

-

On the Javascript side:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var url = "localhost/index.php?page=user&choice=getlist";
    $("#list").autocomplete({json_url:url,height:6});
});
```

On the PHP side:

```
$arr[] = array(//filled with array data );

print json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: Sounds like a fault with the plugin. The obvious solution for the plugin authors would be to cancel outstanding AJAX requests before making a new one...

Comment: There are a number of events you could use in AutoComplete http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#event-search to bind/unbind the autocomplete while it's working i.e. search, select, close - personally I like the fact that it keeps firing as I want my results to trim as the user types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I just had to move a parameter 'json_cache' in the .js file outside of the callback function to fix this problem.